# Reformat Custom Text to Time

Tags: excel

I have a column in Excel of data that is supposed to be minutes played by NBA basketball players. However, when I imported this data, 42 minutes and 24 seconds actually came in as a custom format of "[h]:mm:ss" which makes its value in the cell "1/1/1900  6:24:00 PM" instead of 42:24.

I'm wondering if there is a formula to drag down an adjacent column to reformat this data or a different work around. Whenever I copy/paste into a new column with the desired mm:ss format, it changes 42 minutes, 24 seconds to 24:00.

Thanks for any and all help! Let me know if you need any other clarification.

Comment: How is the time entered in a cell? Is it `0:42:24`? or like "42 minutes 24 seconds"?

Comment: It appears in the cell as "42:24:00", but when you look at the formula bar it appears as "1/1/1900 6:24:00 PM". I'm hoping to do per minute calculations via this data, so leaving it as the date format will make it impossible to do these calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is this:

```
=A2/60
```

...and then copy downward.